# How to set alert severity by name of alert?

Tags: pagerduty

All my alerts are critical except for one, called "not a critical alert". When this alert is triggered though, it has a critical severity. How can I set pagerduty to make this specific type of alert low severity?

Answer (score 2):

Using the [event rule capabilities](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/rulesets#event-rule-actions) within PagerDuty, it is possible to change the severity of an alert.

Depending on the alert severity, you may want to configure your services to use [dynamic notifications](https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/dynamic-notifications), so that you are notified appropriately.
e.g. critical/error = phone call, warning/info = push/email.

For example, you could create an event rule that matches based on the alert summary, then updates the severity as needed.

#### Matching Condition

[image]

#### Action

[image]